# Entity Framework 7 (Beta7) migration script generating invalid table name

Tags: sql-server, powershell, entity-framework-core

When I generate a migration script using the ef 7 powershell commands

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial -c MyDbContext
dnx ef migrations script -c MyDbContext
```

I get a script that has, in the first few lines, the following;

```
Using context 'MyDbContext'.
Generating up script for migration '20151001104737_Initial'.
IF OBJECT_ID(N'__MigrationHistory') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE [__MigrationHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_HistoryRow] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );

GO
```

When I run the script on my SQL Databases to apply my migration I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>     Incorrect syntax near 'MyDbContext'.
>     Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 98
>     Invalid object name '__MigrationHistory'.

I have run this script on SQL Server database versions 11, 12 & 13 and I get the same error throughout. It is clearly complaining that the table name __MigrationHistory isnt a valid table name it seems.

Comment: Naive solution but try `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. The rest of the script actually works fine. (all the other tables get created except for this one) I want to say that its the double underscore prefix but I doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the problem

I was piping the ef command into a file and the first two lines are just descriptions of what is going on while the command is running

so if you are doing something like

```
dnx ef migrations script -c MyDbContext > myscript.sql
```

then make sure to remove the first two lines before running the script

Comment: You can just do `dnx ef migrations script -c MyDbContext -o  myscript.sql`

Comment: This relates to issue [#2883](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2883). We should make piping/redirecting work.